# Pasar de pulgadas a píxeles

Tags: interfaz-gráfica

El Photoshop me creo un problemita o mi técnica no es la apropiada. 
Lo que pasa es esto. 
Estoy aprendiendo el tema del responsive y resulta que . 
Pues trate de ingeniarmela . 
Como todo diseñador tengo un tipómetro y que hize... 
Pues medi mi cell con mi tipómetro en pulgadas y puse esa mismas pulgada en photoshop como cuando una va a llevar un trabajo a imprenta. 
Pero en este caso puse las pulgadas y luego lo cambie a pixeles . 
ADIVINEN hicimos el css con y cuando vimos el resultado las medidas no eran. 
:( 
las medidas salieron super diminutas a la hora del resultado.

la pregunta es. Como se puede hacer eso. Pasar de pulgadas a píxeles ? que técnicas usais ?

Comment: Bienvenido. Es recomendable que sigas el [tour] y consultes [ask]. Por ejemplo, si bien está bien que describas lo que has intentado falta que indiques lo buscado/investigado antes de publicar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente no puedes hacer eso, la transformación de `px` a `inch` es dispositivo dependiente, es decir, única por dispositivo.

Cuando tu compras un dispositivo la pantalla tiene una información técnica la cual indica la densidad de pixeles, se puede calcular usando la siguiente fórmula

```
densidad = pulgadas / pixeles
```

Utilizando análisis dimensional es fácil ver que

```
[densidad] = inch / px = ppi (pixeles per inch)
```

Por un ejemplo, mi dispositivo pantalla de escritorio tiene una densidad de `90 ppi`, lo cual indica que `90px = 1 inch`, así que si quiero transformar `300px` en `inch` basta hacer lo siguiente

```
300px * ( [1 inch] / [90 px]) = 300/90 inch 
~= 3.33 inch
```

Así que en mi pantalla `300px` equivalen a `3.33 inch` o bien `8.46cm`
, no obstante el cálculo es correcto sólo con dispositivos cuyo `ppi` sea `90`

Nota: los `ppi` no son lo mismo que `dpi`, los `dpi` lo usan las impresoras, así que aquí hay más problemas... puesto que aunque en tu pantalla el resultado mida las dimensiones correctas, cuando imprimes el resultado en una hoja de papel verás que puede ser mucho menor al esperado.

Para más información puedes consultar este enlace
http://sebastien-gabriel.com/designers-guide-to-dpi/

Comment: No quiero pasar de pixeles a inches. Si no, de pulgadas a pixeles y con unA regla.
yo entendido un poquito de lo que me explicas. me dices que el cell es independiente que no es lo mismo la masa que pixeles. que el cell tiene una información técnica que dice la masa o densidad (por esto entiendo. Que la densidad es la  masa y que el mundo dentro de las computadoras no es el mimo. No se puede medir con una regla y luego poner esa medida a pixeles. Si esto es así... Cual seria la forma de medir el tamaño exacto del el cell? Ya que con una regla no se puede.

Comment: @wilson __1.__  `inch` es `pulgada`, simplemente opté por dejar su nombre original para que puedas buscar fácilmente información. __2.__ El término `densidad` se refiere a una razón,  no importando las medidas pertinentes, la `densidad` de la que tú hablas se le llama `densidad volumétrica`, que nada tiene que ver con la `densidad` empleada en mi respuesta (no interviene la masa) .

Comment: @wilson  __3.__ Sí puedes medir el dispositivo con una regla, para optener su `densidad`, primero debes ver la información del dispositivo, en él encontrarás sus medidas en `px`, luego con una regla mides la pantalla en `inch` , luego aplicas la fórmula `densidad = pixeles / pulgadas` y obtendrás la densidad correspondiente.

Comment: @wilson te invito a editar tu respuesta, con la siguiente información __1.__ Medidas en `px` (la debes ver en el `OS` del dispositivo). __2.__ Medidas en `inch` (`pulgadas`, la debes medir con una regla, o buscar la información en el `OS`), con esa información podré calcular su `densidad` y decirte cuántos `pixeles` hay por cada `pulgada`

Answer (score 0):

Si todo tu photoshop está en pulgadas (que me ha pasado) usualmente cambio la configuración del photoshop.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Preferencias->Unidades y reglas->Unidades->Texto
(Será necesario cerrar y abrir de nuevo el programa)

Esto no es 100% fiable, pero un archivo PSD de mucho contenido ayuda bastante a la hora de convertirlo a HTML/CSS

Comment: la idea es tomar las medidas del cell y pasarlas a pixeles. 
pero lo hice con una regla y cuando pase a pixele como me dices, no funciono. 
Lo otro que hice fue tomar un  un screen a el cell y las medidas se suponen que son exacta, pero al ponerlas en el photoshop la imagen es grande y cuando pongo esa medida de la foto me sale bien cuando achico la pantalla del chrome. Pero a la hora de verlo en el cell no es la misma medida se ponen super grande.
lo que quiero es tomar una medid que me de justo en la pantalla cuando se achica como cuando se ve en el cell.